# Do I need to add a port to ApplicationInitialization in web.config

Tags: azure, iis, azure-deployment-slots

I want to do a slot deployment in Azure that automatically swaps the slots if deployment is successful. For that I have an endpoint that returns 200 if everything's fine, returns nothing if anything's wrong (no response).
I have this code in my web.config:

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
  <add initializationPage="/validate" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

My app does not run on port 80. Will it still find the app and request the page ?

PS.: I can't test this without opening a pull request and getting it merged. And the team prefers to keep the project's history clean.

Comment: I'd imagine you don't need to, since your app can listen to many ports. IIS makes the init request, it knows which process is running your app.

Comment: @xyious, Any luck with this

Comment: @AstroBoy nope. As far as I remember we kinda just gave up on (automatic) slot deployments (for unrelated reasons).

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationInitialization only works with port 80 and will apparently always add ":80"